# Convert nvarchar(50) to datetime (Second's part not coming after update the table)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datetime

i would also like to convert my nvarchar(50) timecode to datetime type. My code is this one: (example time 27.03.2013 17:11:27)

```
UPDATE test
set mytime = CONVERT(nvarchar(50), convert(datetime, mytime, 104))
alter table test
alter column mytime datetime
```

Result: 2013-03-27 17:11:00.000

i always get the result without seconds! All seconds are reseted to zero.

i want to convert my dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm:ss to datetime with seconds!

The View of this Conversion looks good but not after i update the table!!!

```
select mytime, convert(datetime, mytime, 104)
from test
```

Result: 27.03.2013 17:11:27         2013-03-27 17:11:27.000

What i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

**[Here is SQL Fiddel Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e4d87/1)**

**You can try below steps**

```
CREATE TABLE test
    ([mytime] varchar(50))
;

INSERT INTO test
    ([mytime])
VALUES
    ('27.03.2013 17:11:27')
;

Alter Table test
add mytimeTemp datetime;


set dateformat dmy;

update test
set mytimeTemp = mytime;

update test
set mytimeTemp = '';

alter table test
alter column mytime datetime;

alter table test
drop column mytimetemp;
```

Comment: @DarkoMaraz : If it is a solution to your problem then plz mark as answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

because you are using 104, change to other style like 109 or 113.

If there are no right style format that suite you. You can WRITE A function to customize it LIKE BELOW

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnGeneral_FormatDateString] (
    @dtDate     DATETIME,
    @iFormat    VARCHAR(20)
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(64) 
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @dtDateVC VARCHAR(64) 

    SELECT @dtDateVC = CASE @iFormat 
    WHEN 'DD MMM YYYY' THEN RIGHT('0' + CAST(DAY(@dtDate) AS VARCHAR),2) +  + SPACE(1) + LEFT(DATENAME(MONTH, CONVERT(DATETIME, @dtDate, 120)),3)  + SPACE(1) + CAST(YEAR(@dtDate) AS VARCHAR) 

    WHEN 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM 24' THEN CONVERT(CHAR(10), @dtDate, 23) + ' ' +  CONVERT(CHAR(8), @dtDate, 8) --1.2.0.00

    ELSE  
        'Invalid format specified' 
    END 
    RETURN @dtDateVC 
END
```

Comment: If i set the style to 109 or 113 i get the error: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: the problem is that in the view the conversion is correct but not if i update the table! It seems to be a sql bug....